# Javascript Function that Redirects User / Changes Text after "Submit" is Clicked

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

Trying to develop javascript that redirects the user back to the home page after they submit their name and email. The order should go like this:

1.) User clicks "Request a Brochure..."
[image]

2.) This window opens up in Portrait format, 400 x 350. User fills out name and email and clicks "Submit"
[image]

3.) User is redirected back to the original page, text now reads "Request Submitted..." and the fill out form window is closed.
[image]

Currently, if the user clicks the "Request A Brochure..." hyperlink they are lead to a new page (rather than a new window opening up on top of this page). Here is my HTML for that:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Castaway Vacations, LLC</title>
<script src="castaway.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css">
</head>
<body leftmargin=0 rightmargin=0 bgcolor=#ffcc99 
text=#993300 link=#993300 vlink=#996633>

<br>
<table width=100% border=0 cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0>
<tr>
<td width=95% align="right" bgcolor=#ffffff>
<img src="castaway_logo.jpg">
<br>
<font face=arial>Vacations, LLC</font></td>
<td bgcolor=#ffffff>&nbsp;</td>  
</tr>
</table>
<br><br>
<div align="center">
<table width=600>
<tr>
<td width=300 valign="top">
   <font face=arial size=3><b><i>Select Mood...</i></b></font><br><br>
   <font face=arial>
   <a style="text-decoration:none"
   onClick="change_color();" href="#">Romantic</a><br><br>
   <a style="text-decoration:none" 
   onClick="change_color2();" href="#">Adventure</a><br><br>
   <a style="text-decoration:none" 
   onClick="change_color3();" href="#">Relaxation</a><br><br>
   <a style="text-decoration:none" 
   onClick="change_color4();" href="#">Family</a><br><br><br><br>
   <a style="text-decoration:none" 
   href="form.html" onClick="window.open(this.href,'targetWindow',
   'toolbar=no, location=no, status=no, menubar=no, scrollbars=yes,
   resizable=yes,width=400, height=350');
   return false;">Request Submitted...</a>
   </font>
   </td>
   <td align="center"><img id="rom_main" src="orig_main.jpg">
   <br><i>Your Vacation Awaits!

  </tr>
</center>
</body>
</html>
</DOCTYPE>
```

And here is the Javascript for the Index. All it does is change the text/hyperlink colors when clicked:

```
function change_color(){
  document.body.style.color = "#FF0066";
  document.body.style.background = "Thistle";
  document.getElementById("rom_main").src = "rom_main.jpg";
  var list = document.getElementsByTagName("a");     
  for (i = 0; i < list.length; i++) { 
  list[i].style.color = "#FF0066";  
  }

}

function change_color2(){
  document.body.style.color = "blue";
  document.body.style.background = "#87CEEB";
  document.getElementById("rom_main").src = "adv_main.jpg";
  var list = document.getElementsByTagName("a");     
  for (i = 0; i < list.length; i++) { 
  list[i].style.color = "blue";  
  }
}

function change_color3(){
  document.body.style.color = "green";
  document.body.style.background = "#CCFF99";
  document.getElementById("rom_main").src = "rel_main.jpg";
  var list = document.getElementsByTagName("a");     
  for (i = 0; i < list.length; i++) { 
  list[i].style.color = "green";  
  }
}

function change_color4(){
  document.body.style.color = "brown";
  document.body.style.background = "#66CCFF";
  document.getElementById("rom_main").src = "fam_main.jpg";
  var list = document.getElementsByTagName("a");     
  for (i = 0; i < list.length; i++) { 
  list[i].style.color = "brown";  
  }
}
```

Then, here is the HTML for the form:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Castaway Vacations, LLC</title>
<script src="form.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="form.css">
</head>
<body leftmargin=0 rightmargin=0>
<br>
<table width=100% border=0 cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0>
<tr>
<td width=95% align=right bgcolor=#ffffff><img src="castaway_logo.jpg">
<br>
<font face=arial>Vacations, LLC</font></td>
<td bgcolor=#ffffff>&nbsp;</td>  
</tr>
</table>
<br><br>

<center>
<table width=85%>
  <tr>
   <td valign=top>
   <form id="emailform" method="post" 
   onsubmit="return validateEmailForm();" action="form.html">
   <div id="name-field">
   Name:<br>     
   <input id="name" name="textname" size=35 >
   </div>
   <br><br>
   <div id="email-field">
   E-mail:<br>
   <input id="email" name="textname" size=35 >
   </div>
   <br><br>
   <input type="submit" name="button1" value="Submit">
   </td>
  </tr>
</center>

</body>
</html>
```

The Javascript for the form:

```
function validateEmailForm(){
var name = document.getElementById('name');
var email = document.getElementById('email');
var error = false;
var focusElem;

if(name.value.length == 0){
    error = true;
    var nameField = document.getElementById('name-field');
    nameField.innerHTML = nameField.innerHTML + " *Name is required";
    focusElem = name;
}

if(email.value.length == 0){
    error = true;
    var emailField = document.getElementById('email-field');
    emailField.innerHTML = emailField.innerHTML + " 
    *Email is required";
    if(focusElem == undefined){
        focusElem = email;
      }
    }

    if(error){
    focusElem.focus();
      return false;
    }
    return true;
}

var form = document.getElementById("emailform");
form.addEventListener("submit", function(){
window.location.href = "index.html";
});
```

And the CSS for the form:

```
#errors { 
clear:both;
color: red;
}
```

To start with, I don't know where the Javascript would go that would open form in Portrait mode - does it go in the js file for index or for form? Thanks for any help/direction/advice!

Answer (score 1):

Basically, when your form is submitted, you need to change the `window.location.href` property to the URL you want the user to be redirected to (your home page in this situation).

```
var form = document.getElementById("emailform");
form.addEventListener("submit", function(){
    window.location.href = URLofTheHomePage;
});
```

Make sure to replace `URLofTheHomePage` with the actual URL of your home page.

Comment: This caused the rest of the javascript in the file not to work. Does it matter where I place this new var? Also do I put quotes around URLofTheHomePage? (which is index.html by the way).

Comment: I've noticed you already have a onsubmit handler. I'll update my answer with the improved code.

Comment: There, updated it. Use the new code now. Also, yes, you need quotes around your URL, since it's a string.

Comment: Okay it's still not working. Is where I placed it correct? I just put it at the bottom of my javascript for form.html (you can see the full edit above).

Comment: You put it inside validateEmailForm() function. Place it at the bottom of your JS file.

Comment: I'm new to JS so you'll have to forgive me, but I don't see how it's inside of the validateEmailForm() function. What would it look like to be placed at the bottom? Here is a JSfiddle if that helps you explain. 

http://jsfiddle.net/HappyHands31/rw8p0gxu/

Comment: In your StackOverflow post it's inside the function, and in the JSfiddle it's not... You also have an extra "{" on line 30 in your JSFiddle. Delete it, and then try again.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I would recommend. It seems you can write code so I would not feed you details.

1. Onclick() of "Request A Brochure", Open up a Modal with your html in it. You can use something like following css for Modal

> ```
> #overlay {
>          visibility: hidden;
>          position: absolute;
>          left: 0px;
>          top: 0px;
>          width:100%;
>          height:100%;
>          text-align:center;
>          z-index: 1000; }
> ```

2. On submit of form - send data for processing and fire an event.
3. Keep "Request a Brochure" html element to listen to this event and update its content only when event occurred not when dialog is cancelled.
4. Instead of event, you can also have a callback method which gets called from validateEmailForm() after it validates data. In this callback you can change the contents of your home page without reloading it. for e.g.

> ```
> validateEmailForm(function() {
>    // update html element content
> });
>
> function validateEmailForm()
> { 
>   if (data valid) {
>     callback(); 
>   }
> }
> ```